# Admob interstitial ad fatal error in iOS9, Swift, SpriteKit game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, admob, ios9

I'm getting a fatal crash when trying to place an admob interstitial ad in my Swift, SpriteKit, iOS9 game.

I believe I've got the Admob SDK and dependencies set-up properly, via CocoaPods, following the streamlined instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start

My Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
use_frameworks!

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'

target 'My Project's Name' do

end
```

Then I follow this guide:
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial

It's a game, so I put the code in GameViewController.swift (rather than ViewController.swift.)  The relevant bits:

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

var interstitial: GADInterstitial!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("Google Mobile Ads SDK version: " + GADRequest.sdkVersion())

    self.interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()

    // unrelated code
    }
}

func createAndLoadInterstitial() -> GADInterstitial {
    var interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910")
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial.loadRequest(GADRequest())
    return interstitial
}


 func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    self.interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}


func gameOver() {
    if self.interstitial.isReady {
        self.interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self)
    }
}
```

I get the proper output in console: `Google Mobile Ads SDK version: afma-sdk-i-v7.7.0`

But I get this error on the gameOver() function:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

It appears to be on the `if self.interstitial.isReady` line.

I did make the App Transport Security (ATS) allowance detailed here:
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios9

XML looks like:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

I also tried changing out the ad unit ID from the above (the test code Google has in instructions) with my actual ad ID, but no dice -- same error.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Cheers,
Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you checking that the ad has preloaded correctly and therefore is not nil?

You can also add a check just before the ...isReady line

```
 guard self.interstitial != nil else { return }
```

to make sure its not nil.

If you are still stuck I have an ads helper on gitHub you an check out, it includes adMob as well

https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift2-iAds-AdMob-CustomAds-Helper

Comment: Thanks, that guard statement does stop the crash, but my interstitial is still nil, so no ads load. I'm looking through your helper code.  I used CocoaPods to bring in the SDK and dependencies and I don't use iAd, so not sure this is a fit, but will give it a spin.  Appreciate the help.  Cheers.

Comment: Oh, also, given this is a game without a ViewController.swift file, is it safe to assume instructions for ViewController.swift can just be applied to GameViewController.swift?

Comment: Yeah should work on any view controller. I will update this helper once I fully understand what's happening with iAd. Still not sure why your ads are nil, are you using the correct adMob ID for testing?

Comment: Your ads helper on github worked perfectly, crashoveride777.  Thanks much! I'm not entirely clear how I switch from debug mode to live mode -- does that just happen automatically if app is downloaded via TestFlight or App Store?  Or is there a manual change I'd need to make?

Comment: Hey, it will change automatically if you have set a DEBUG flag in your project. Just follow the instructions on gitHub. It will automatically go into release mode when you sent it to the appStore. Not 100% sure about test flight since I havent done that yet.